# I get Py4JJavaError when using randomsplit() on google colab

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to split my data on pyspark dataframe, I used the code;

````
```train, validation, test = movie_ratings_spark.randomSplit([6, 2, 2])
# cache data
train.cache()
validation.cache()
test.cache()```
````

I get the following error;

````
```Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o46.randomSplit.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(BoxesRunTime.java:116)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.array_update(ScalaRunTime.scala:77)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.copyToArray(IterableLike.scala:256)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.copyToArray$(IterableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.copyToArray(Iterable.scala:56)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.copyToArray(TraversableOnce.scala:283)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.copyToArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:282)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.copyToArray(Traversable.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:291)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toArray(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.randomSplit(Dataset.scala:2292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```
````

I did some searches and get they might be compatibility issues between pyspark 2.1 and python3. I'm using google colab, can anyone who has been able to solve this problem please help. Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the docstring of `randomSplit` method:

> Randomly splits this :class:`DataFrame` with the provided weights.
>
> :param weights: list of doubles as weights with which to split the :class:`DataFrame`.
> Weights will be normalized if they don't sum up to 1.0.
>
> :param seed: The seed for sampling.

so you should pass a list of doubles instead of integers

```
train, validation, test = movie_ratings_spark.randomSplit([6., 2., 2.])
```